# Update statement with unmatched condition

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have a update query as follows-

```
udate table1 tbl_out
set column1 =
    (select colValue from table1 t1, table2 t2
    where table1.product_id = table2.product_id
    and t1.id = tbl_out.id)
where tbl_out.column1 is null;
```

This works well. But there are some columns with `table1.product_id` value as null.
So for these records `where table1.product_id = table2.product_id` condition is not satisfied and records are not updated.

I tried adding this condition as follows -

```
where (table1.product_id = table2.product_id OR table1.product_id is null)
and t1.id = tbl_out.id
```

but this will return more than 1 row and above update statement will fail.
I know there is something wrong in this condition that  might be pretty  simple but coud not figure out.

Ca anyone help me on this?

Comment: So which lookup table provides `colValue` in the subquery? `table1` or `table2`?

Answer (score 0):

```
   udate table1 tbl_out
 set column1 =
(select colValue from table1 t1, table2 t2
where nvl(table1.product_id,table2.product_id) = table2.product_id
and t1.id = tbl_out.id)
where tbl_out.column1 is null;
```

Comment: I tried this but it gives exception "subquery returns more than 1 row)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a simple correlated subquery, meaning that you don't need the `JOIN` in the subquery:

```
update table1 tbl_out
    set column1 = (select t2.colValue
                   from table2 t2
                   where t2.product_id = tbl_out.product_id
                  )
    where tbl_out.column1 is null;
```

You might want an `exists` clause as well:

```
update table1 tbl_out
    set column1 = (select t2.colValue
                   from table2 t2
                   where t2.product_id = tbl_out.product_id
                  )
    where tbl_out.column1 is null and
          exists (select 1
                  from table2 t2
                  where t2.product_id = tbl_out.product_id
                 );
```

EDIT:

If you have a `NULL` value in `table2` and you are trying to treat that as a valid key:

```
update table1 tbl_out
    set column1 = (select t2.colValue
                   from table2 t2
                   where t2.product_id = tbl_out.product_id or
                         (t2.product_id is null and tbl_out.product_id is null)
                  )
    where tbl_out.column1 is null;
```

Comment: But this will not update the records with product_id null. I want to update those records as well.

Comment: With what value?